# What demographic plays squash the most?

Tags: squash

I don't know anyone that plays squash so I wanted to know among what demographic it is most popular.

Answer (score 5):

From [http://www.squashtalk.com*](http://www.squashtalk.com/business/summer07/sp07-8-3.htm):

- Sex:

  - 84% male.
  - 16% female.
- Age

  - Under-15, 2%;
  - 16–24, 21%;
  - 25–34, 25%;
  - 35–44, 26%,
  - 45–54, 18%;
  - 55–64, 6%;
  - 65+, 2%.

*<sub>Please note that the data is from 2007</sub>